# Is there a django template equivalent of the python string multiplication function?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

In python I can write `"Hello" * 5` and get

```
HelloHelloHelloHelloHello
```

Is there a way to do this in a django template? Something like `{% multiply "Hello" 5 %}` or as a filter `{% "Hello"|multiply:"5" %}`

Or maybe a "repeat" loop control? Something like:

```
{% repeat 5 %}
Hello
{% endrepeat %}
```

I can write a filter or tag myself, but was wondering if I could save myself some trouble.

If someone can authoritatively say that there is no built-in capability such as I require, that would be a perfectly acceptable answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in capability such as you require.

That would be a trivial tag to make for yourself - there are some helpful examples in the Django docs.

I suppose you could hack something together by using something like `{% for x in "12345" %}Hello{% endfor %}` but that is a horrible hack.

Comment: I love the hack! It may not be pretty but gets the job done, and it is quite legible.

Comment: Haha maybe I shouldn't have put that in there - remember that someone else could work on this code after you and wish bad things to happen to you ;)

Answer (score 19):

Here's another hack:

```
{% for x in ""|ljust:"100" %}
    Hello World!
{% endfor %}
```

I'm using an empty string as the value here, and I repeat the thing 100x. You can also use a variable to determine the number of repeats with this hack :) just replace "100" with the variable.

```
{% for x in ""|ljust:repeat_count %}
    Hello World!
{% endfor %}
```

### Or make your own...

you can make the multiply filter quite easily ([more on making your own template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)):

In an installed app (e.g., included in your INSTALLED_APPS setting), add a "templatetags" module and a file called "string_multiply.py"

So you will have something like this:

```
your_app
  + templatetags
  | + __init__.py
  | + string_multiply.py 
  + __init__.py
  + models.py
```

plus whatever else you have in your app...

### Here's your string_multiply.py

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.filter
def multiply(string, times):
    return string * times
```

Yup that's the whole thing...

### And then in your template

```
{% load string_multiply %}

Chris Brown:
{% filter multiply:3 %}
  Yeah!
{% endfilter %}

You (x5):
{{ request.user.username|multiply:5 }}
```

**The output of which will be:**

```
Chris Brown:
  Yeah!
  Yeah! 
  Yeah!

You (x5):
Koliber ServicesKoliber ServicesKoliber ServicesKoliber ServicesKoliber Services
```